# How to To Create a CSR with keytool and Generate a Signed Certificate for the Certificate Signing Request

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I need to Create a CSR with keytool and Generate a Signed Certificate for the Certificate Signing Request.

I followed the below steps:

**1. create new keystore**

```
keytool -genkey -alias keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \
-keystore keystore.jks -dname "CN=*.jananath.com, OU=Home,O=Home,L=SL,S=WS,C=LK" \
-storepass mypassword -keypass mypassword
```

**2. Generated a csr for the keystore created above**

```
keytool -certreq -alias keystore -file keystore.csr -keystore keystore.jks
```

**3. Need to create a self signed certificate with the `keystore.csr` created above**

**4. Need to import the CA certificate into the client keystore**

But I don't know how to proceed with `Step 3` and `Step 4`

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Step 1 (`-genkey[pair]`) already generated a self-signed cert. But to use a CA cert at the client in step 4, you would need a CA-signed cert for the server in step 3, NOT a self-signed cert. Do you in fact want a CA-signed cert? If so, from what CA or what kind of CA e.g. well-known public, specialized domain, enterprise internal, or your own personal/private one?

Comment: Actually in the  `Step 4` it should be `Need to import the Self Signed certificate in to the client keystore`

Comment: Are there any free CA services that produces, `Root certificate`, `Intermediate certificates` and `SSL Certificate signed by CA` ?

Comment: That makes even less sense; if you want to use a self-signed cert in step 4, you don't need steps 2 and 3 and any CA at all. There are lots of SSL/TLS CAs that provide free service to certain populations, and at least two to the public, letsencrypt.org and cacert.org, the former of which is trusted by most clients (like browsers and programming environments) by default, plus you can make your own. All CAs _create_ a leaf cert when properly requested, and _already have_ and provide copies of their root and applicable intermediate certs. You need to pin down what you want to do specifically.